# Bootstrap 4, button with icons, vertical aligned PC vs Phone

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, bootstrap-4

#### **Codesandbox reproduction** here (very simple code): https://codesandbox.io/s/w76l88p8nk

**The problem**:

On my PC (Chrome 67.0.3396.99 x64 Windows 10) the button looks like this:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/41120635/42765237-d61e2812-8917-11e8-87fd-ad120375e7bf.png

On my mobile phone (Chrome 67.0.3396.87, Android 8) the button looks like this:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/41120635/42765364-272ef498-8918-11e8-865d-92b8bfe63ccb.png

It is amazing on my phone. It is perfectly good vertical aligned.

Why the same code on the PC is different aligned?

I don't wanna use code like: `d-flex align-items-center` because it seems exaggerated to me. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset line-height or use line-height:0; for button.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/5373x18w6k  I used padding for 10px but you should use 5rem. *rem is some error in codesandbox.

Comment: This is a bad trick which involves other problems. It's not a good solution.